# Изменить тип задачи в JIRA на python

Tags: python, jira, jira-api

Пытаюсь изменить тип существующей задачи в  JIRA. Напрашивается решение которое ниже, но почему то не работает. Другие поля задачи изменяются нормально.

```
from jira.client import JIRA

options = {'server': 'https://jira.server.net'}
jira = JIRA(options=options, basic_auth=('asset_manager_bot', 'VCIpCw15'))
issue = jira.issue('OUT-30207')  # обьект задачи
issue.update(fields={'issuetype': {'id': '10401'}}) #  изменяю тип задачи
```